# php mail form doesn't work

Tags: php, mail-form

I think I fixed this. This was the original:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];;
    $subject = $email = $_POST['subject'];;

    $email_to = $email;
    $header = 'From: 1totheN <website@1tothen.com>' . "\r\n";
    function clean_text($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }
    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_text($email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_text($email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_text($message)."\n";
    @mail($email_to, $subject, $email_message, $header);
    echo "Your message has been sent.";

}
?>
```

Here's the  markup on the HTML page:

```
<form class="contact-form" id="subscribeForm" action="mail.php" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="name" class="required" placeholder="YOUR NAME">
       <input type="text" name="email" class="required email" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS">
       <input type="text" name="subject" class="required last" placeholder="SUBJECT">
       <textarea name="message" placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE"></textarea>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT YOUR MESSAGE">
       <h6 id="form_result">Your email will not be published.</h6>
</form>
```

This is the fix:

```
$email_to = "webmail@1tothen.com";
$header = 'From: 1totheN <webmail@1tothen.com>' . "\r\n";
$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_text($name)."\n";
```

I think that fixes it. I added an email to the $email_to field, and added the $name. Seems to work.

Comment: be more specific that isn't working? $subject = $email = $_POST['subject'];; is incorrect, should be $subject = $_POST['subject'];

Comment: Can you post your `<form></form>` as well?

Comment: @0n35 - pretty sure that's the problem, why not post it as the answer?

Comment: This code is riddled with many errors and no empty field checking. Someone could just enter `me@here` and will still execute. And what's with the `clean_text()` function? It doesn't do anything for domain checking. You'd be better off using [`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`](http://php.net/manual/filter.filters.validate.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below now works. It's just small syntactic mistakes, you had a few additional `;` and this line is wrong and presumably a mistake: `$subject = $email = $_POST['subject'];`

I also moved the function outside of the `if` statement...it's not incorrect to have it there, it just looks a bit weird.

```
function clean_text($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
    return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];

    $email_to = $email;
    $header = 'From: 1totheN <website@1tothen.com>' . "\r\n";
    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_text($email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_text($email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_text($message)."\n";
    @mail($email_to, $subject, $email_message, $header);
    echo "Your message has been sent.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, @anthonygore, that did tidy it up, but not quite enough. I just threw in an email into the $email_to parameter and it has worked! I appreciate your help.